# Decided what methods go to which file

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am still learning and working through some examples. One is a game with a `GameScene` and a view controller. At times when a new method is creating I am unsure of why it is going into the `GameScene` over the view controller and vice versa. Is there an easy way or rule to help identify what functions should go where?

Answer (score 0):

The view controller is responsible for creating game scenes and presenting them.
Anything global between all the scenes might go in the viewcontroller (like initialising a database).

Any logic specific to the scene itself can go in the gamescene for example setting up sprite nodes, handling user input etc.

On a side note it can sometimes be a good idea to move some logic out of the scene into a separate file. In this case the scene would only be used to display what it's told and perform animations and handle user input.
This would be an MVC model, and you'd have a separate file for handling all the logic. Then you'd have a controller which handles interaction between the two.

Comment: Initializing a database is most certainly not a task for a view controller, naturally, because it doesn't have anything to do with controlling a view. You should have a dedicated data layer that the view controller accesses.

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant.